# Dome Image Projection

Tags: glsl, fragment-shader

Im trying to create a GLSL fragment shader which projects an image to a dome. The input would be a sampler2D texture, an elevation and an azimuth.

The result should look like the following gif's.

Elevation between 0 and 90 degree (in this gif its between -90 and 90)

[image: Valid XHTML].

Azimuth between 0 and 360 degree

[image: Valid XHTML].

Right now my code looks like this:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform float u_time;
uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform sampler2D u_texture_0;
uniform sampler2D u_texture_1;

// INPUT
const float azimuth=0.;// clockwise 360 degree
const float altitude=90.;// 0-90 dregree -> 90 = center
const float scale=1.;

// CALC
const float PI=3.14159265359;
const float azimuthRad=azimuth*PI/180.;
const float altitudeNormalization=sin((1.-(altitude/90.)));

float box(in vec2 _st,in vec2 _size){
    _size=vec2(.5)-_size*.5;
    vec2 uv=smoothstep(_size,_size+vec2(.001),_st);
    uv*=smoothstep(_size,_size+vec2(.001),vec2(1.)-_st);
    return uv.x*uv.y;
}

mat2 rotate(float angle){
    return mat2(cos(angle),-sin(angle),sin(angle),cos(angle));
}

void main(){
    vec2 st=gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution;
    vec4 color = texture2D(u_texture_1,st); // set background grid

    vec2 vPos=st;

    float aperture=180.;
    float apertureHalf=.5*aperture*(PI/180.);
    float maxFactor=sin(apertureHalf);

    // to unit sphere -> -1 - 1
    vPos=vec2(2.*vPos-1.);

    float l=length(vPos);
    if(l<=1.){
        float x=maxFactor*vPos.x;
        float y=maxFactor*vPos.y;
        float n=length(vec2(x,y));
        float z=sqrt(1.-n*n);
        float r=atan(n,z)/PI;
        float phi=atan(y,x);
        float u=r*cos(phi)+.5;
        float v=r*sin(phi)+.5;
        vec2 uv=vec2(u,v);

        // translate
        vec2 translate=vec2(sin(azimuthRad),cos(azimuthRad));
        uv+=translate*altitudeNormalization;

        // rotate
        uv-=.5;
        uv=rotate(PI-azimuthRad)*uv;
        uv+=.5;

        // scale
        float size=.5*scale;

        float box=box(uv,vec2(.5*size));

        uv.x*=-1.;
        uv.y*=-1.;

        if(box>=.1){
            vec3 b=vec3(box);
            //    gl_FragColor=vec4(b,1.);
            //uv *= box;
            color += texture2D(u_texture_0,uv);
        }
        gl_FragColor= color;

    }

}
```

As you can see there are two things wrong, the texture is only displayed partially (I know that I kind of cut it out which is for sure wrong) and the distortion is also wrong. Any help would be apretiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is, that you use a scaled uv coordinates for the box test:

> ```c
> float size=.5*scale;
>
> float box=box(uv,vec2(.5*size));
> ```

You have to consider this scale when you do the texture look up the texture. Furthermore you wrongly add 0.5 to the uv coordinates:

> ```c
> float u=r*cos(phi)+.5;
> float v=r*sin(phi)+.5;
> ```

Set up the uv coordinates in range [-1.0, 1.0]:

```c
vec2 uv = vec2(r*cos(phi), r*sin(phi));
```

Translate, rotate and scale it (e.g. `const float scale = 8.0;`):

```c
// translate
vec2 translate = vec2(sin(azimuthRad), cos(azimuthRad));
uv += translate * altitudeNormalization;

// rotate
uv = rotate(PI-azimuthRad)*uv;

// scale
uv = uv * scale;
```

Transform the `uv` coordinate from range [-1.0, 1.0] to [0.0, 1.0] and do a correct box test:

```c
uv = uv * 0.5 + 0.5; 

vec2 boxtest = step(0.0, uv) * step(uv, vec2(1.0));

if (boxtest.x * boxtest.y > 0.0)
    color += texture2D(u_texture_0, uv);
```

Fragment shader main:

```c
void main(){
    vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution;
    vec4 color = texture2D(u_texture_1,st); // set background grid

    float aperture=180.;
    float apertureHalf=.5*aperture*(PI/180.);
    float maxFactor=sin(apertureHalf);

    // to unit sphere -> -1 - 1
    vec2 vPos = st * 2.0 - 1.0;

    float l=length(vPos);
    if(l<=1.){
        float x = maxFactor*vPos.x;
        float y = maxFactor*vPos.y;
        float n = length(vec2(x,y));
        float z = sqrt(1.-n*n);
        float r = atan(n,z)/PI;
        float phi = atan(y,x);
        float u = r*cos(phi);
        float v = r*sin(phi);
        vec2 uv = vec2(r*cos(phi), r*sin(phi));

        // translate
        vec2 translate = vec2(sin(azimuthRad), cos(azimuthRad));
        uv += translate * altitudeNormalization;

        // rotate
        uv = rotate(PI-azimuthRad)*uv;

        // scale
        uv = uv * scale;

        uv = uv * 0.5 + 0.5; 

        vec2 boxtest = step(0.0, uv) * step(uv, vec2(1.0));

        if (boxtest.x * boxtest.y > 0.0)
            color += texture2D(u_texture_0, uv);
    }

    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```